# loading form data and passing it as a json to api

Tags: javascript, html, json, azure, forms

I am trying to use azure personalize and make food predictions. I have attached the code I am using without the API key.

I want to use the forms and get the `contextFeatures` and `actions` to pass into API rather than writing statically and rank them using `azure-personalize` API.

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append(
  "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
);
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  contextFeatures: [
    {
      timeOfDay: "Morning",
    },
  ],
  actions: [
    {
      id: "NewsArticle",
      features: [
        {
          type: "News",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "SportsArticle",
      features: [
        {
          type: "Sports",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "EntertainmentArticle",
      features: [
        {
          type: "Entertainment",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  excludedActions: ["SportsArticle"],
  eventId: "75269AD0-BFEE-4598-8196-C57383D38E10",
  deferActivation: false,
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: "follow",
};

fetch(
  "https://ibs-recommendations.cognitiveservices.azure.com/personalizer/v1.0/rank",
  requestOptions
)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <form>
      <label for="fname">Food:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
      <br />
      <label for="lname">Ingriends one:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
      <br />
      <label for="lnametwo">Ingriend two:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="lnametwo" name="lnametwo" />
      <br />
      <label for="quantity">Amount of food</label>
      <br />
      <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
      <br />
      <label for="time">Pick the time:</label>
      <select id="time" name="time">
        <option value="breakfast">BreakFast</option>
        <option value="lunch">Lunch</option>
        <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there something wrong with the code? Have you debugged it?

Comment: There is no wrong with the code. in the javascript file, I have given raw data manually in `JSON.stringify` as `contextFeatures` and `actions` but I want it to take from the form @Andy

Answer (score 0):

You can check for HTTP triggers webhook and bindings to use request and response objects

Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#http-triggers-and-bindings) from Microsoft.

As we can get the details as properties (body, headers, method).

In the below way we can access the request and response.

```
// You can access your HTTP request off the context ...
if(context.req.body.emoji === ':pizza:') context.log('Yay!');
// and also set your HTTP response
context.res = { status: 202, body: 'You successfully ordered more coffee!' };
```